# Spritekit - Spritenode in front of Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sprite-kit

I have this tableview that is added to my scene by a subclass and it is added like so to the scene

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    gameTableView.frame = CGRect(x:14,y:70, width: frame.maxX / 1.08, height: frame.maxY/0.9)

    self.scene?.view?.addSubview(gameTableView)
    gameTableView.reloadData()

    universalBackButton = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orange, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    universalBackButton.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX - universalBackButton.size.width * 0.7, y: -frame.maxY + universalBackButton.size.height)
    universalBackButton.zPosition = 100001
    self.scene?.addChild(universalBackButton)

    itemShopMenu = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orange, size: CGSize(width: 75, height: 50))
    itemShopMenu.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX + universalBackButton.size.width * 0.7, y: -frame.maxY + itemShopMenu.size.height)
    itemShopMenu.zPosition = 100001
    self.scene?.addChild(itemShopMenu)
}
```

But when I go to add buttons so I can leave the tableview scene they're behind the tableview and not in front of it. I have had little to no experience using subviews with scenes and don't know how to get the spritenodes to be in front of the tableview instead of behind it so they can be tapped to execute a function. is there anyway I can add the spritenodes in front of the tableview so they can be pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteKit is optimized for layering sprites within an SKView - not for placing above other UIViews. Why not achieve the same effect by creating UI buttons and layering them on top instead of using sprites as buttons?

```
let universalBackButton = UIButton()...
```